# reloading page in angular2 according to location.hash

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an application and i would like to reload the page but this fails to work by it keeps on reloading the page

```
 ngOnInit() {
   location.reload();
 }
```

I have also tried

```
 ngOnInit() {
    console.log("inited");
    let win = (window as any);
    if(win.location.hash !== '#/home?loaded' ) {
        win.location = win.location + '#/home?loaded';
        win.location.reload();
    }
 }
```

In both instances above the page keeps on reloading but i would like to reload only once

Comment: What is the use case?

Comment: The use case is that we have developed a complicated carousel in jquery which needs a page refresh for it to work whenever a user navigates to homepage, Rather than redisigning the carousel again refreshing the page works

Comment: which browser are you using? is that IE?

Comment: chrome browser not IE

Answer (score -1):

Angular2 develops Single Page applications which, in most cases, are not meant to be reloaded. If you'd like to change the content of the page, I suggest you to use the Angular2 binding ( one way or two-way ) and use the framework's detection strategy.

Comment: True but its not necessarily limited in other options like page reloads